# Why Nash or correlated equilibrium require complete information?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, algorithmic-game-theory

In games of complete information, there are common solution concepts such as Nash equilibrium and correlated equilibrium. The idea is that each player is playing a best response.
My question is - Why do we need complete information for these solutions?

If I understand correctly, Mixed Nash equilibrium (and therefore also correlated equilibrium) is guaranteed in every (finite) game, regardless of the information players have on their opponents.

If the information is necessary in order to compute the equilibrium then I'm still not sure why. There are methods that don't require this information. For example, best response dynamics, in which on each turn, one player picks a "beneficial deviation". To do this, you need to know only your own utility function. Another example is no regret algorithms, that are used to compute correlated equilibrium. The Weighted Majority, each player updates his weights only based his cost vector.

Thanks!

Comment: Although you ask about "necessary in order to compute the equilibrium", I would first parse out the need for complete information to *define* a Nash equilibrium.  See for example how it is defined in [Nash equilibrium -- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium).

Comment: Thanks @hardmath! As far as I understand, the complete information concept refers to the knowledge of the players. Utility functions exist and defined, they're just unknown to other players. Therefore, equilibrium is defined. Moreover, even in this case, without knowing the utility functions of the other players, a player may ask himself "Can I benefit from changing my strategy?"

Comment: I believe "complete information" refers to each player knowing the *strategy* of the other player.  Equilibrium then refers to whether a player can gain an advantage by changing their strategy. Of course there is a notion of "utility" embedded in the payoff matrix, such that the payoffs need not be symmetric.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you think we need complete information? And how do you model incomplete information?

Comment: This previous Question, [Does a mixed NE in complete information induce a mixed BNE in incomplete information](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3957025/does-a-mixed-ne-in-complete-information-induce-a-mixed-bne-in-incomplete-informa), might be of interest.